# How to know which app is bad

Tags: bug-reporting, error-handling

I use Ubuntu Studio 18.04.3, with the additional backports PPA to get LTS, in three desktop PCs and one laptop.

Since a week, or so, each time I turn ON one of my desktop PCs, when all the initialization process is made (after the desktop is full shown), I get an error message:

```
There was a problem with one of the Ubuntu packages.
Do you want to send a report about this?
[Yes] [No]
```

But... I wonder how can I know which package is and what kind of error is? Where can I find that kind of information?

BTW: I've sent the asked report each time I've got the message, but... Until now, I don't have any kind of message from the Ubuntu team about that.

Comment: Look for a .crash file in /var/crash   The filename itself will tell you the program/library where the problem was detected, plus date/time stamp will tell you when. You can view the file (it's text) with the file starting pretty easy to understand before it moves to hex-dump & not human-readable...   It's these files that you submit using `ubuntu-bug` or when you click "yes" to report it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your data! I will see that folder.

Comment: fyi:  .crash files that have been submitted should have been renamed to .crash.upload; but yes there are times where submission fails & message can repeat. If .crash files are old, you can `rm` (remove) them safely (it'll cause the repeating message to disappear).  Also you won't always hear from a Ubuntu team member, or will never hear if you weren't the first person reporting such a bug (but it's still very useful, as a bug that impacts 100 people will get more attention than a bug impacting on a single user; ie. it adds heat).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look for a .crash file in /var/crash/

The filename itself will tell you the program/library where the problem was detected, plus date/time stamp will tell you when.

You can view the file (it's text) with the file starting pretty easy to understand before it moves to hex-dump & not really human-readable...

It's these *.crash* files that you submit using `ubuntu-bug` or when you click "yes" to report it.

fyi: *.crash* files that have been submitted should have been renamed to *.crash.upload*, but yes there are times where submissions fail & the message can repeat. If .crash files are old (ie. dated a few sessions ago), you can `rm` (remove) them safely which will stop the 'problem detected, submit report' question repeating.

Also please note you won't always hear from a Ubuntu team member on filing a bug report.  Also please note  crash reports aren't uploaded if it's a common bug (enough info has been grabbed from prior reporters), but it's still useful information, as a bug that impacts 100 people will get more attention than a bug impacting only a single user (in bug terms more reports adds heat).

Lastly, Thank you for taking the time to report these bug(s), and helping to make Ubuntu better.